# Is there any chances of data loss in SQL CDC?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I have CDC enabled on my project SQL database. Are there any scenarios where the CDC does not work. In those cases will it be possible to get back the previous tracking data?

Comment: This would be a better fit on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and they should be logged in the [sys.dm_cdc_error DMV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/change-data-capture-sys-dm-cdc-errors?view=sql-server-2017) for the previous 32 sessions which can be found in [sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/change-data-capture-sys-dm-cdc-log-scan-sessions?view=sql-server-2017)

There are cases where you would not be able to get *tracking* data that doesn't involve *failure* of CDC:

1. The table isn't enabled for CDC
2. CDC was enabled after the data was changed
3. You prune the change tables without storing them elsewhere, like an audit server or archiving them (i.e. the cleanup job that runs daily deletes entries > 4320 minutes old)
4. You change the source table (add columns) which weren't originally identified for capture when CDC was enabled
5. You have a failure, and are unable to backup the tail log. Note, log truncation advances after the the capture process gathers the changes that are marked for capture.
6. Corruption to the change tables

Comment: Are there ways to retrieve the audit data in case CDC didn't worked?

Comment: how would it have been audited? Do you have auditing set up on your instance for this? One broad answer to your question would be to restore a backup to another instance prior to the change and compare the table in question to production. This wouldn't hold all the metadata associated with CDC of course.

Comment: I meant will we be able to get any change tracking data from the past since the CDC encountered any error?

Comment: perhaps, it depends on #2 and #3 in my answer, and what the error was.